# This app is not allowed to query for scheme whatsapp

Tags: ios, ios-universal-links

Im trying to use universal links to other apps.
I get the following error "This app is not allowed to query for scheme whatsapp" when trying to connect Facebook or whatsapp.

I followed other answers for this questions and added LSApplicationQueriesSchemes array to plist of the project but when I call
schemeIsAvailable("whatsapp://") I get the same error again.

any help will be appreciated

Comment: can you please add what you have added in `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes ` ?

Comment: item 0 String fb                  item 1 String whatsapp

Comment: so your plist scheme looks like this:http://i.stack.imgur.com/WZu4f.png? check last line

Comment: yep exactly like that

Comment: just fixed it - had to delete drives data, clean and reinstall the app. thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

If we want to access whatsapp for sharing text or image from any app then we have to install whatsapp on that device from which we run app

And we can't install whatsapp on iphone simulator

Answer (score 0):

delete derived data, clean and reinstall the app solved my issue.

Comment: Can you explain what is drives data?

Comment: @RajanMaheshwari They probably meant "derived data".

Comment: @RajanMaheshwari Derived Data include index, build output and logs and here how to clean it http://www.developerinsider.in/2016/03/16/clean-xcode-cache-quick-fix/

Comment: @VineetChoudhary I know what is derived data. The user101010 has written drives data which confused me. I was referring to some disk drive and all after reading drives data. And the link you gave is a old process to clean derived data. Use `Alcatraz` instead. I have already made a video tutorial for that too. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qoZeKMLuRKY